# Extracting single value from the DB ORACLE

Tags: php, sql, oracle

How do i extract the single value from one row in the database and put it in the HTML tag,
my code looks like this,

```
<?php 
$projectName    = strval($_GET['project']); 
$thicknessValue = intval($_GET['thicknessValue']);
$baseplateValue = strval($_GET['baseplateValue']);

$query = "SELECT QTY_REQUIRED FROM COMPONENT_CUTTING 
                WHERE THICKNESS = :thicknessVal 
                AND PROJECT_NAME = :projectName
                AND BASE_PLATE = :baseplateVal
                AND REQUEST_STATUS = 'OPEN'";
$result = oci_parse($conn, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($result, ":projectName", $projectName);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ":thicknessVal", $thicknessValue);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ":baseplateVal", $baseplateValue);

oci_execute($result);
?>

<?php 
    while($row = oci_fetch_num($result, OCI_NUM)) { ?>
        <input type="number" name="quantityToCut" min="0" max="<?php echo $row[QTY_REQUIRED] ?>" type="text" value="">
<?php } ?>
```

the error shows like this ,

Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_fetch_num() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Component_request\findQuantity.php on line 44

Comment: Usually one would head to the PHP manual when encountering an error like this - http://php.net/manual/ref.oci8.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `oci_fetch_array`  in the while, and do `<?php echo $row[0] ?>`

Comment: so when i do this in the html, 

`<?php 
        while($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_NUM)) { ?>
            <?php echo $row[QTY_REQUIRED]; ?>
    <?php } ?>`

the value doesnt appear. Whats wrong with this ?

Comment: instead of QTY_REQUIRED, you put 0 because you use OCI_NUM so it gives an array of numbers (in order of the columns in the select)

Answer (score 3):

So. what `oci_fetch_num` is supposed to mean then? The correct method is [oci_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/oci_fetch_array)

```
while($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_NUM))
```

As Phil pointed out if you use OCI_NUM as fetch mode then you have to use numeric indexes. You could simply do

```
while($row = oci_fetch_array($result))      // Numeric and Associative both indices
```

Comment: Might want to mention that OP should use `$row[0]` if using `OCI_NUM`

Comment: Thanks Phil, just did